# Unwanted List pass by Reference in Function

Tags: python, computer-science

I have this code:

```
import scipy
import scipy.linalg

def LU(A):
    n = scipy.shape(A)[0]
    U = A
    L = scipy.identity(n)

    for j in range(1,n):
        for i in range(j+1,n+1):
            L[i-1,j-1] = U[i-1,j-1]/U[j-1,j-1]
            for k in range(j,n+1):
                U[i-1,k-1] = U[i-1,k-1] - L[i-1,j-1] * U[j-1,k-1]
    return L,U


a = scipy.matrix([[1.0,1.0],[2.0,1.0]])
L,U = LU(a)
print L
print U
print a
print scipy.dot(L,U)
```

How would I fix the unwanted pass by reference in LU() where U points to where A is and changes to U also change A.

Comment: Python *always* passes by reference.

Comment: The difference between passing by reference and passing by value is that passing by value copies the whole object. So, copy the object.

Comment: You could do the copy on the call:  `L, U = LU(copy.deepcopy(a))`

Comment: @DanielRoseman I disagree, I think python *never* passes by reference. But I admit, my understanding of these things may be incorrect. To my understanding, passing a reference isn't the same thing as passing by reference, which is generally characterized by having assignments to the variable being seen by the caller. I.E. `def special(&x): x = 4` then `y = 3; special(y); print(y)` would print `4`

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent modifications to `A` by making a copy immediately:

```
import copy

def LU(A):
    n = scipy.shape(A)[0]
    U = copy.deepcopy(A)
    L = scipy.identity(n)
    # ...
```